# Dynamic corner radius for a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cornerradius

I am trying to make my uitextview's corner radius dynamic depending on the number of lines displayed. The text is retrieved from my backend, so the number of lines will vary...

I've tried setting the corner radius in viewDidLoad after the text view is created by using its frame but for some reason that doesn't work. I'm assuming its returning 0 for some reason.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

(I'm cutting out a lot of code just to keep it simple here. Everything is added to the subview properly. Everything is added programmatically - not using the storyboard at all here. The text views display as expected besides the corner radius)

inside viewDidLoad:

```
    questionOneTextBox.layer.cornerRadius = self.questionOneTextBox.frame.height * 0.5
    questionTwoTextBox.layer.cornerRadius = self.questionTwoTextBox.frame.height * 0.5
```

Comment: Are you saying that you are adding the `UITextField` programmatically, not using storyboards?

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating the text view programmatically with constraints, then you need to call `self.questionOneTextBox.layoutIfNeeded()` and `self.questionTwoTextBox.layoutIfNeeded()`. This will initialise the bounds.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Create the Text View

        self.textView = UITextView()

        self.textView.text = "This text will appear in the text view."

        self.textView.backgroundColor = .lightGray

        self.view.addSubview(self.textView)

        // Set the constraints

        self.textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.textView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 280).isActive = true

        self.textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true

        self.textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 60).isActive = true

        self.textView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        // This will initialise the bounds

        self.textView.layoutIfNeeded()

        // Now the this should work

        self.textView.layer.cornerRadius = self.textView.frame.height * 0.5
    }
}
```

This what this code looks like.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Views are not laid out (sized) when `viewDidLoad` is called. Move your corner radius sizing to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `viewWillAppear`, at which time the sizing has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set `clipsToBounds` to true? This might be causing your problem. I hope this helped

Comment: I tested that when I did my answer and it is not needed.